# pagination in nodejs, express

Tags: node.js, express, pagination

how to apply concept of pagination in nodejs. I have posted my whole nodejs 
practice module but i am atuck with the concept of pagination. I need to 
show 4 entries on each page .
**Front-end**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/deletechecks" method="post">
<table style="margin-top: 20px" table border="1"  text- 
align:ccellspacing="20px" cellpadding="15px" width="100%">
<% for(var i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++) { %>
    <tr></td>
        <td> <%= data[i].catname %> </td>
        <td> <%= data[i].status %> </td>
        <td> <%= data[i].id %> </td>
        <td> <a href="/delete/<%= data[i].id %>"> delete</a></td>
        <td> <a href="/view/<%= data[i].id %>"> view</a></td>
        <td> <a href="/update/<%= data[i].id %>"> update</a></td>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="<%= data[i].id 
        %>">delete <%=data[i].id %>  </td>
       </tr>
       <% } %>
       </table>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete Selected">

       </div>
       </form>
       </body>
       </html>
```

**Backend**

```
    var express= require('express');
    var app = express();
    var url = require('url')
    var bodyparser= require('body-parser');
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var session= require('express-session');
    app.use(session({secret:'hello'}));

    app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true})); 

    app.set ("view engine" , 'ejs');


    var con = mysql.createConnection({
   host: "localhost",
    user:'root',
    password: "",
   database:'blog'
    });
   con.connect(function(err) {
 if(err) throw err;
 console.log("connected!");
  });
app.get('/',function(req,res){
res.render('blog1');
 });
app.post('/action',function(req,res){
var title=req.body.cat;
var status =req.body.sel ;
var q = "insert into category set catname = '"+title+"', 
status='"+status+"'";
con.query(q,function(err,result){
    if(err)
        throw err;
    else
    res.redirect('/viewdata');

   });
   });
   app.get('/viewdata', function(req,res) {
   var w= "select * from category";
   con.query(w, function(err,result){
   res.render('showdata',{data:result});

  });
  });

  app.get('/delete/:a',function(req,res){
  var z= req.params.a;
     var d= "delete from category where id='"+z+"'";
 con.query(d,function(err,result){
    if(err) throw err;
    res.redirect('/viewdata');
 });

 });
app.get('/view/:a',function(req,res){
var z= req.params.a;// url se dynamic value nikalne ke liye
var d= "select * from category where id='"+z+"' ";
con.query(d,function(err,result) {
if(err) throw err;
res.render('showbyid',{data:result});
});
});
app.get('/update/:id', function(req,res){
var d= req.params.id
var z= "select * from category where id='"+d+"'";
con.query(z,function(err,result) {
    if(err) throw err;
    res.render('blog1', {data:result});
});
});
app.post('/new_action/:id',function(req,res){
 var x = req.body.cat;
 var y = req.body.sel;
 var z = req.params.id;
 var updated ="update category set catname ='"+x+"', status='"+y+"' where 
 id='"+z+"' ";
 con.query(updated,function(err,result){
    if(err)
        throw err;
    else
        res.redirect('/viewdata');
 });
 });
app.get('/viewdata',function(req,res){
var q= "select * from category";
con.query(q,function(err,result){
    res.render("viewdata",{data:result});

});
});

app.post('/deletechecks',function(req,res){
var ch = req.body.check;
if(typeof ch == "string")
{
    var h= "delete from category where id='"+ch+"'";
        console.log(h);     
        con.query(h,function(err,result)
        {
            console.log('deleted');
        });
}   
else
{
    for( var i=0;i<ch.length;i++)
    {
        var h= "delete from category where id='"+ch[i]+"'";
        console.log(h);     
        con.query(h,function(err,result)
        {
            console.log('deleted');
        });
    }
 } 
  res.redirect('/viewdata');
 });
app.get('/login',function(req,res){
if(req.session.name)
{
    res.redirect("/dashboard");
}
else {
res.render('login');
}
});
 app.post('/new',function(req,res){
 var email = req.body.emailfield;
 var password = req.body.passwordfield;
 var updated ="  select count (email) as val  from  admin where email = 
 '"+email+"' and password='"+password+"' and status='active'";
 con.query(updated,function(err,result){
    if(err)
        throw err;
    if(result[0].val)//
    {
        req.session.name=email;
        res.redirect("/dashboard");
    }

    else
    {
        res.redirect("/login");
    }
    });
    });
    app.get("/dashboard",function(req,res)
    {
   if(!req.session.name)
    {
    res.redirect("/login");
   }
   res.render("dashboard")
    });
   app.get("/logout" , function(req,res){
  })

  app.listen(8080);
```

**code to insert into database is also included included along with delete  and other operations. Code is working perfectally fine for rest of the 
queries only concept of pagination is to be applied here.  **

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with node js. This is an application design question. Pagination is achieved in 2 ways

- Client side. Get entire dataset and paginate your response to show first 4, which technically would be  data[0] through data[3].
- on click of next page, get 4 to 7 , or if you have pages ( data.length/4), you get data[(page-1)*4] to data[(page-1)*4+3]
- Server side :

  ```
     app.get('/viewdata/:page', function (req, res) {
       var page = req.params.page
       var w = //some SP to get nth page data;
       con.query(w, function (err, result) {
          res.render('showdata', { data: result });
       });
    });
  ```

Comment: i have created the database in my xampp server but i am not able to write the proper code for that in my ejs and js file . Can you help me on that ?

Comment: this is not a code writing service. I can help you if you are facing issues with your code

Comment: also another approach, get partial data on client side and do ajax which is a hybrid of the methods you mentioned